# How to show documents from multiple remote publication in the template?

Tags: meteor

I wish to use Meteor to subscribe a few remote publication via DDP. Then show the documents in one template. Here is what I did:

```js
Posts = {};

var lists = [
  {server: "localhost:4000"},
  {server: "localhost:5000"}
];

var startup = function () {
  _.each(lists, function (list) {
    var connection = DDP.connect(`http://${list.server}`);
    Posts[`${list.server}`] = new Mongo.Collection('posts', {connection: connection});
    connection.subscribe("allPosts");
  });
}

startup();
```

This file is at client folder. Every startup, in this example, at browser I have two client collections Posts["localhost:4000"] and Posts["localhost:5000"], both are same schema. I know this format (Collection[server]) is ugly, please tell me if there is a better way.

Is there a way to show these client collections in the same template with reactive. Like this:

```js
Template.registerHelper("posts", function () {
  return Posts.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
});
```

I think Connected Client is a big part of the Meteor. There should be a best practice to solve this problem, right?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Connect to multiple servers via DDP, then observe their collections reactive via cursor.observeChanges.

```js
Posts = {};
PostsHandle = {};
// LocalPosts is a local collection lived at browser.
LocalPosts = new Mongo.Collection(null); // null means local

// userId is generated by another Meteor app.
var lists = [
  {server: "localhost:4000", userId: [
    "hocm8Cd3SjztwtiBr",
    "492WZqeqCxrDqfG5u"
  ]},
  {server: "localhost:5000", userId: [
    "X3oicwXho45xzmyc6",
    "iZY4CdELFN9eQv5sa"
  ]}
];

var connect = function () {
  _.each(lists, function (list) {
    console.log("connect:", list.server, list.userId);
    var connection = DDP.connect(`http://${list.server}`);
    Posts[`${list.server}`] = new Mongo.Collection('posts', {connection: connection}); // 'posts' should be same with remote collection name.
    PostsHandle[`${list.server}`] = connection.subscribe("posts", list.userId);
  });
};

var observe = function () {
  _.each(PostsHandle, function (handle, server) {
    Tracker.autorun(function () {
      if (handle.ready()) {
        console.log(server, handle.ready());
        // learn from http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes
        // thank you cursor.observeChanges
        var cursor = Posts[server].find();
        var cursorHandle = cursor.observeChanges({
          added: function (id, post) {
            console.log("added:", id, post);
            piece._id = id; // sync post's _id
            LocalPosts.insert(post);
          },
          removed: function (id) {
            console.log("removed:", id);
            LocalPosts.remove(id);
          }
        });
      }
    })
  });
}

Template.posts.onCreated(function () {
  connect(); // template level subscriptions
});

Template.posts.helpers({
  posts: function () {
    observe();
    return LocalPosts.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}); // sort reactive
  }
});
```